# "How to make a functional Navbar"

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to React and I'm trying to implement Navbar with react-bootstrap. I have the navigation bar set up but its not actually linking to any of my pages.

I've tried looking through the documentation but there's not much information there. I've looked at other posts but they all seem to be using older versions of react-bootstrap or not using it at all.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./components/stylesheets/index.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./components/stylesheets/App.css";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <NavBar />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, Form, FormControl, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./stylesheets/NavBar.css";

class NavBar extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="bar">
        <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">CALC-U</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="ml-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#about">About</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#updates">Updates</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#profile">Profile</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

I want the app to open up to the Home page automatically, and then open up the other pages if the button is clicked on in the navBar.

Comment: share your routing configuration

Comment: I haven't made a routing configuration, so should I do that? @VahidAkhtar

Comment: yeah you need to create that. for your reference https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: @Igueorguiev you can check example created for your help https://stackoverflow.com/a/58723195/6544460

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: I've created a working example, you can check the code: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boostrap-navbar-react-router-utyvt)

---

Seems like you're not using `react-router` for handling the links.

First you need to wrap your component with a BrowserRouter like so:

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const app = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And in `NavBar.js`, inside a `<Switch />` component, you declare the routes:

```
import { Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
//(...)
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
</Switch>
```

In your case, you case use `Link` component inside your Nav.Link:

```
<Nav className="ml-auto">
  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/">Home</Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/about">About</Nav.Link>
</Nav>
```

Same applies if you want to add more links to the NavBar.

Answer (score 0):

Sample application using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction) for Navbar

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
          <Route path="/updates" exact component={Updates} />
          <Route path="/profile" exact component={Profile} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
const Home = () => <h1>Home</h1>;
const About = () => <h1>About</h1>;
const Updates = () => <h1>Updates</h1>;
const Profile = () => <h1>Profile</h1>;
```

NavBar.js

```
class NavBar extends React.Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="bar">
        <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">CALC-U</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="ml-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="/">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="/about">About</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="/updates">Updates</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="/profile">Profile</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```